# Python Excel - How to turn sheet name into sheet number

Tags: excel, python-2.7, csv, xlrd, xlwt

In this program I create a sheet on the input excel file called new_sheet.

I need the sheet number of the sheet without having to look at the excel file.

**How do I return the sheet number from the program?**

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
import csv

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xls')

worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('new_sheet')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not understand well if you want count how many sheets there are in your Excel file or if you want know, gave the name of sheet at which number correspond; 
anyway, if you want count how many sheets there are in an Excel file you can proceed in this way:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xls')
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('new_sheet')

# number of sheet
print workbook.nsheets
```

Instead, if you want know the corresponding number of sheets from the name you can proceed in this way:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xls', on_demand=True)
for index, sheet in enumerate(workbook.sheet_names()):
    if sheet == <name of your sheet>:
        print index
```

With *on_demand=True*, you can open file not loading automatically.

Regards

Comment: Lets say I create the sheet new_sheet, how do i get the sheet number from that

Comment: With the second method. "workbook.sheet_names()" return a list with all sheets name

Comment: right but how do I get the sheet number. Ex: the first sheet's sheet number is 0, 2nd is 1, 3rd is 2

Comment: The index of list is the number of sheet

Comment: My bad I just did that, sorry

Comment: No problem, it's useful for other user